# unable to transition red to white background wallpaper

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was learning animation in JS. i was able to move objects using delta but got stuck when making background colour transitions of a div. problem seems to be in the javascript but cant figure out.
i want color of the box to change from red to white on mouse over.

```js
//var from = [0, 0, 0], to = [255, 0 ,0];
var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
var duration = 500;
function del1(progress) {
 return progress;
}
function step(delt1) {
 /*elem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + 
     parseInt(from[0] + delta * (to[0] - from[0])) + ',' + 
  parseInt(from[1] + delta * (to[1] - from[1])) + ',' + 
  parseInt(from[2] + delta * (to[2] - from[2])) + ')' ;*/
  var from = [255,0,0], to = [255,255,255];
  
  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' +
        Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((delt1 * (to[0]-from[0])) + from[0], 10), 255), 0) + ',' +
        Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((delt1 * (to[1]-from[1])) + from[1], 10), 255), 0) + ',' +
        Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((delt1 * (to[2]-from[2])) + from[2], 10), 255), 0) + ')';
}
funtion trans() {
 var start = new Date();
 var id = setInterval(change,1);
 function change() {
     var timePassed = new Date() - start;
  var progress = timePassed / duration;
  if(progress > 1) progress = 1;
  var delta = del1(progress);
  step(delta);
  if(progress == 1) clearInterval(id);
 }
}
```

```css
#animate {
    margin: auto;
 background-color: red;
 width: 250px;
 height: 125px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
 </head>
    <body>
     <div id="animate" onmouseover="trans()">
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its a simple spelling mistake, you spelled `function` wrong

```
function trans()
```

Comment: We all make mistakes, this is why I keep my console open in my browser when doing more complex js.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is just an exercise for you, but a simpler way to do it would be with CSS!

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
var duration = 500;

function del1(progress) {
  return progress;
}

function step(delt1) {
  /*elem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + 
      parseInt(from[0] + delta * (to[0] - from[0])) + ',' + 
   parseInt(from[1] + delta * (to[1] - from[1])) + ',' + 
   parseInt(from[2] + delta * (to[2] - from[2])) + ')' ;*/
  var from = [255, 0, 0],
    to = [255, 255, 255];

  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' +
    Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((delt1 * (to[0] - from[0])) + from[0], 10), 255), 0) + ',' +
    Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((delt1 * (to[1] - from[1])) + from[1], 10), 255), 0) + ',' +
    Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((delt1 * (to[2] - from[2])) + from[2], 10), 255), 0) + ')';
}
```

```css
#animate {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

#animate:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="animate">
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
```